# python How can i change my plotlib figure colors? with numpy

Tags: python, plotly

i m using plotlib (for the first time)
and there is my graph:
[image]

But now, i want to change the colors (blue, red and green).

There is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as px
 
 
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
 
plot = px.Figure(data=[
    px.Bar( name = '1', x = x, y = [75, 75, 50]),
    px.Bar( name = '2', x = x, y = [75, 75, 50]),
    px.Bar( name = '3', x = x, y = [0, 0, 50] )
])


plot.update_layout(barmode='stack')
                  
plot.show()
```

I have tried:

```
px.Bar( name = '1', x = x, y = [75, 75, 50], colors = "red")  or this              color_discrete_sequence =['green'],
```

and i checked the documentation but it doesnt work and i have everytime the same message

````
raise err
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Bar: 'color'

Did you mean "base"?

    Valid properties:
        alignmentgroup
```


Thanks for your help
````

Comment: I really do not recommend import plotly graph objects as `px`.  better to use convention of `go` so when you use Plotly Express you use standard convention for that too

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer on a forum:

i just had to do :

```
    px.Bar( name = '1', x = x, y = [75, 75, 50], marker_color='#E5EBF7'),
```